# $_FILES is always empty when uploading image files to PHP?

Tags: php, html

Here is the form in HTML

```
<form method="post" action="reg.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <table width="100%" class="table4" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
        <tr>
            <td align="right">Picture：</td>
            <td><input type="file" id="pic1" name="pic1" /></td>
        </tr>
   </table>   

   <input type="submit"  id="btnsubmit" name="btnsubmit" value="send" /></td>
</form>
```

In reg.php

```
    print "<pre>";
    print_r($_FILES);
    print "</pre>"; 
    $pic1 = $_FILES['pic1']['name'];
    $pic1_type = $_FILES['pic1']['type'];
    $pic1_size = $_FILES['pic1']['size'];
```

But the _FILES array is alwats empty:

```
Array
(
)

Notice: Undefined index: pic1 in reg.php on line 31
```

Please help!

My file is a 20kb png file and from phpinfo():

```
file_uploads    On  On

max_file_uploads    20  20

post_max_size   10M 10M

upload_max_filesize 10M 10M
```

Comment: How are you submitting the form?

Comment: I'd start by trying to eliminate possible causes. Use the browser's developer tools (or a program like Fiddler) to see whether the uploaded file is being sent by the browser. That will tell you whether it's a problem at the client end or the server. If the file is being sent, then you need to look at your PHP code or your PHP config. If the file isn't being sent, then you need to look at your HTML.

Comment: Have you checked your php.ini for `file_uploads = On` and other related settings (i.e. `upload_max_filesize`)?

Comment: I did, file_uploads = On and upload_max_filesize is 10M

Comment: Your code works for me. Check PHP settings.

Comment: How big is the file you are trying to upload? What are the post_max_size and upload_max_filesize values set to in your php.ini?

Comment: upload_tmp_dir? Is it available for writing?

Comment: btw better way:
`var_dump($_FILES);
if(isset($_FILES['pic1'])) {
$pic1 = $_FILES['pic1']['name'];
$pic1_type = $_FILES['pic1']['type'];
$pic1_size = $_FILES['pic1']['size'];
}`

Comment: Your code has nothing wrong ! try removing `action="reg.php"` if you have both the `php` and `html` code on the same page !!

Comment: Any error message in the webservers log files?

Comment: Why is it that you're posting to **reg.php** and the error refers to a file called **_reg.php**?

Comment: put `ini_set('display_errors',1); error_reporting(E_ALL);` at the top of your php file and re-submit.

Comment: @ Prisoner
error_reporting(E_ALL); was already there, anyway thanks

Comment: @user1659006 - have u tried removing action attribute from `<form>`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only case that I could think of where the keys are not being found are:

- You are unsetting the key for some odd reason.
- `file_uploads` is disabled.

Most probably the uploaded images exceed the maximum size defined in the server's configuration. You can invoke [phpinfo()](http://php.net/phpinfo) to check your current limits.

If you want to change them, just modify the following properties on php.ini as needed:

```
; Maximum file size of post data that PHP will accept.
post_max_size = 20M

; Maximum allowed file size for uploaded files.
upload_max_filesize = 20M
```

Or use [php_value within .htaccess](http://php.net/configuration.changes.modes):

```
php_value upload_max_filesize 100M
php_value post_max_size 100M
```